# Chrome Custom Title Bar Option for Linux

Tags: google-chrome

Does anyone know the command line option to disable Chrome's custom title bar, like the Windows' equivalent of "--disable-features=Windows10CustomTitlebar", but for Linux?

I know that you can use the GTK+ theme and toggle the "Use system title bar and borders" option, but that only affects the main Chrome browser interface. I would like for it to apply to Chrome's windowed apps as well.

I have tried the following options to no avail:

--disable-features=LinuxCustomTitlebar

--disable-features=UbuntuCustomTitlebar

--disable-features=CustomTitlebar

Comment: It turns out that there is no equivalent option for Linux after a going through a [Chromium Codesearch](https://cs.chromium.org/). This inconsistent behaviour has been confirmed to be a bug by the Chromium team. If you would like to get this bug prioritized and fixed soon then you can star the issue [here.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=968647&q=Use%20system%20title%20bar%20and%20borders&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the system's default title bars in windowed Chrome apps you will have to create a `.desktop` shortcut manually.

Below is an example for YouTube but can be modified for any website.

### Desktop shortcut

Create `.desktop` file: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/youtube.desktop`

Add:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=YouTube
Icon=<custom path to your icons>/youtube.png
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app=https://youtube.com
StartupWMClass=youtube.com
```

### Icon

Icons can be retrieved by browsing to the website and going into Chrome's menu: `More tools` > `Create shortcut...`

The icon will be located in its corresponding extension directory: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions`

Select the icon image with the largest size.

### StartupWMClass

If your app URL contains a `/`, then it must be replaced with `__`.

Example:

`StartupWMClass=play.google.com/music` becomes `StartupWMClass=play.google.com__music`

### Testing

Restart GNOME:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `r` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Open app from application list.

### Results

Before:
[image: Windowed Chrome apps without system title bar]

After:
[image: Windowed Chrome apps with system title bar]